# Installing applications for multiple users

Tags: raspbian

Apologies for what appears to be (and no doubt is) a very simple question. I have a Pi and want to set up three accounts - one for each of my kids. This I have done.

I now want to install some software ... let's say Minecraft-Pi. I would like to install this once and have all the users be able to access it.

When I install the software in `/home/user1/mcpi` then it works for that user. Clearly no other user can access it. So where can I install it where every user can access it?

First of all I tried doing the install in `/usr/local/games/mcpi` ... (installing it as the root user) ... but when I do so I get an error (segmentation fault). I have used `chmod` to make sure ALL users have execute permissions so that isn't the problem.

I also have the same question for other software e.g., RetroPie -- this is currently in one of the users home directory but the other users cannot access it.

Any thoughts most welcome!

Thanks
John

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! No problem, we've all been at that simple question stage before :) Have you tried installing to `/opt`? That's what that directory is for, OPTional software. You will also have to create desktop entries for each of the software so that they show up in the menu.

Comment: Thanks - will give that a go. If I want the user to run the application from the command line do I simply need to create a link to the executable in their home drive?

Comment: I believe so, yes. Simply link the desktop file for the software to the user's desktop and it should, mind that I say *should*, work.

Comment: Will try this evening and will report back either way ... cheers

Comment: Cool - it worked. I created a `xxx.desktop` file in the `/home/user/desktop/` directory to link to the `/opt/program`. All slightly complicated. Guess this is why they invented Package Managers! Thanks @RPI Awesomeness